# Why does dpkg give me a "package was interrupted" error?

Tags: 11.10, dpkg, lock

When I try install or remove a software through the terminal, I receive

```
dpkg package was interrupted
```

and further if I use software center to install the same, I receive

```
ttf-mscorefonts-installer errors
```

I tried to solve the same using

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and I receive

```
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in a terminal and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you find you still have a lock it is because the system thinks you still have something using apt.

Close any Software Centre/Synaptic/terminal running an apt command. Reboot if the lock still shows or run from a terminal

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

There should have been an EULA to agree to - tab to OK and enter once the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command is running.

Comment: `sudo dpkg --configure -a` should work without needing to purge the lock, you don't need to rm the lock (you should never do that anyways)

Comment: yup! i had gone there already to eula put wasnt able to continue as i was held up with the **TAB** key.. anyway on using this my desktop got hanged!!! will try suggesting the alternate.thanks!!